# Buttons force mouse into top left of window when dragging

Tags: python, tkinter

I've set up a basic code that makes a draggable overrideredirect tkinter window, but when I add my own custom buttons the window doesnt drag with the buttons but instead flicks the mouse to the top left corner and drags the window from there.

```py
#Imports
import sqlite3,tkinter
#Connects to the database
with sqlite3.connect("apc.db") as db:
    cursor = db.cursor()

#Interface Class
class login_UI(tkinter.Tk):
    #Main Interface Function
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tkinter.Tk.__init__(self, master)
        self.title("Apex Companion")
        self.geometry()
        self.geometry("250x400")
        self.overrideredirect(True)
        self.config(bg="#1e1e1e")
        #Tob Bar Frame
        tb = tkinter.Frame(self,height=20,width=250,bg="#0f0f0f")
        tb.pack_propagate(False)
        #Top Bar Text
        tb_text = tkinter.Label(tb, text="Apex Companion",bg="#0f0f0f",fg="#b4b4b4")
        tb_text.config(font=("Trebuchet",10, "bold"))
        #Top Bar Close
        tb_close = tkinter.Button(tb, height=2, width=3,
                                  text="✕", bg="#0f0f0f", fg="#ffffff",
                                  activebackground="#c94343",activeforeground="#ffffff",
                                  command=self.destroy, bd=0)
        #Top Bar Minimize
        tb_min = tkinter.Button(tb, height=2, width=2,
                                text="—", bg="#0f0f0f",fg="#ffffff"
                                ,bd=0,activeforeground="#ff4e1d",activebackground="#0f0f0f")
        #Top Bar Logo
        self.tb_img = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="logo_apc.gif")
        tb_logo = tkinter.Label(tb,image=self.tb_img,bd=0,justify=tkinter.RIGHT)


        #Top Bar Packing
        tb.pack()
        tb_close.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT)
        tb_min.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT)
        tb_logo.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)
        tb_text.pack()

        #Make Window Draggable
        self._offsetx = 200
        self._offsety = 200
        self.bind('<Button-1>', self.clickwin)
        self.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.dragwin)
    #Window Dragging Events
    def dragwin(self,event):
        x = self.winfo_pointerx() - self._offsetx
        y = self.winfo_pointery() - self._offsety
        self.geometry('+{x}+{y}'.format(x=x,y=y))

    def clickwin(self,event):
        self._offsetx = event.x_root
        self._offsety = event.y_root

    def login_db(self,event):
        print("E")
#Initilize the Interface
login_UI = login_UI()
login_UI.mainloop()
```

I've updated the code to display my entire file. Hopefully this should help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you click on button then `event.x`,`event.y` gives position relative to top-left corner of `Button`, not to top-left corner of window so later it gives wrong results.

this gives correct offset

```
def clickwin(self, event):
    self._offsetx = self.winfo_pointerx() - self.winfo_rootx()
    self._offsety = self.winfo_pointery() - self.winfo_rooty()
```

Now I can move even by dragging Button but dragging button later gives other problem - when I stop draging then button catch click and it close window :)

---

Full code

```
import tkinter

class Win(tkinter.Tk):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tkinter.Tk.__init__(self, master)

        #self.geometry()
        self.geometry("250x400")
        self.overrideredirect(True)
        self.config(bg="#1e1e1e")

        #Tob Bar Frame
        tb = tkinter.Frame(self, height=20, width=250, bg="#0f0f0f")
        tb.pack_propagate(False)
        tb.pack()

        #Top Bar Close
        tb_close = tkinter.Button(tb, height=2, width=3,
                                  text="✕", bg="#0f0f0f", fg="#ffffff",
                                  activebackground="#c94343",activeforeground="#ffffff",
                                  command=self.destroy, bd=0)
        tb_close.pack()

        #Make Window Draggable
        self._offsetx = 0
        self._offsety = 0
        self.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.dragwin)
        self.bind('<Button-1>', self.clickwin)

    #Window Dragging Events
    def dragwin(self,event):
        x = self.winfo_pointerx() - self._offsetx
        y = self.winfo_pointery() - self._offsety
        self.geometry('+{x}+{y}'.format(x=x,y=y))

    def clickwin(self, event):
        self._offsetx = self.winfo_pointerx() - self.winfo_rootx()
        self._offsety = self.winfo_pointery() - self.winfo_rooty()
        print('1.', event.x, event.y)
        print('2.', event.x_root, event.y_root)
        print('3.', self._offsetx, self._offsety)

root = Win()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: With the first set of code the window will work normally as intended for the first drag, but then any other drag after that it flicks the window back to the top left of the screen and drags from where the mouse originally clicked. the second code doesn't seem to work and just raises errors. I'll edit my post to display the full code.

Comment: ok I see problem - second version works correctly but It has to be `self` instead of `root` - I assigned your class to `root`